# Regex: Not empty - no letters

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm rather new to Regex, and i'm working on this particular statement:

*The input can't be empty, and it cannot contain any letters ([a-zA-Z]).*

I have these 2 statements now:

```
Not empty: (?=\\s*\\S).*$)
No letters: ^[^a-zA-Z]
```

I know these 2 work. However, i need to combine them in a single statement (for use with Javascript). I have tried literally everything i can find and can think of. Putting the statements between ()'s, between []'s, separating them with |, combining them with ()(), adding and removing ^ and *$, and every combination thereof. However, it always seems to either be **not empty** or **no letters**, never both.

Can anyone help me combine these 2 statements into 1?

Comment: `/^[^a-zA-Z]+$/` - the `+` ensures there's at least one character.

Comment: ... or just `/^[a-z]+$/i`

Comment: Thanks Absol, that indeed did the trick. I can't believe i just spend hours trying to combine it when it was a simple '+'. Now that i'm typing another question about Regex: Why is it that people always post regex as /regexHere/, but when i use the code i have to remove the /'s? What's the point in typing it with a single /?

Comment: @Mortaza: Regular expressions are often written with forward slashes as *delimiters*. For example, `/re/` is used for the regular expression re. Several languages, including JavaScript, use the same delimiter notation. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9622110/1438393) for an example. Check [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Delimiters) for a brief history of how this came into existence.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following:

```
/^[^a-zA-Z]+$/
```

(note: Niet the Dark Absol commented exactly what I just posted here, before I answered, so if you want to I'll delete my answer so you can pick up the upvotes.)

Comment: This one works :) Absol posted it first in the comment part, but i'll accept your answer for future references.